# Activating data pipeline when new files arrived on S3 using SNS

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-emr, amazon-sns, amazon-data-pipeline

How to activating data pipeline when new files arrived on S3.For EMR scheduling using triggered using SNS when new files arrived on S3.

Comment: Can you explain more about where your trigger would be and for S3 changes, what you exactly want to do(I dont see use of SNS here if you just want to spin emr cluster)

Comment: Issue resolved by using lambda function with [ython environment.
Reffer url https://github.com/amazon-archives/data-pipeline-samples/tree/master/samples/OnDemandWithLamdaFunctions

Comment: @SalimKA create trigger on lambda.lambda will trigger sns and  datapipline using boto3.

Answer (score 1):

**You can execute data pipeline without using SNS. When files will be arrived into S3 Location**

1. Create S3 event which should invoke lambda function.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4kiT.png)
2. Create Lambda Function (Make sure the role which you will give that has s3 , lambda, data pipeline permissions).
3. Paste below code in lambda function to execute data pipeline (mention your data pipeline_id)

```
import boto3 
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try :
        client = boto3.client('datapipeline',region_name='ap-southeast-2')
        s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
        data_pipeline_id="df-09312983K28XXXXXXXX"
        response_pipeline = client.describe_pipelines(pipelineIds=[data_pipeline_id])
        activate = client.activate_pipeline(pipelineId=data_pipeline_id,parameterValues=[])
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception("Pipeline is not found or not active")
```